# In Unix shell scripting, what does the token ${0%/*} mean?

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I have the below code snippet in the file (This the first line in the code leaving the comments):

```
scriptdir=${0%/*}
```

I am unable to figure out what is the value that is assigned to the variable 'scriptdir'

can anyone please explain what **${0%/*}** resolves to?

Thanks

Comment: Look at [Section 2.6.2, Parameter Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html)

Answer (score 3):

The `%` operator tells the shell to remove the shortest suffix of `$0` that matches `/*`. In other words, it expands to the base directory of a given path by removing the last path component.

Some examples:

```
$0                 ${0%/*}
/foo/bar           /foo
/foo/bar/          /foo/bar
/foo/bar/test.txt  /foo/bar
```

It is *almost* equivalent to the `dirname` command, which can recognize a path that ends with `/` as a directory, rather than an "empty" final component.

```
# Not /foo/bar, as with parameter expansion
$ dirname /foo/bar/
/foo
```

Answer (score 0):

`man bash` can be very helpful in times like these (not a great read though).

`$0`/`${0}`, is the name of the script you are executing.

`%/%%` represents the end of `$0` (the suffix), and everything after the `%` represents a pattern, in this case `/*` is "a forward slash followed by any string".

Relevant excerpt from the `man` page:

> `{parameter%word}` `${parameter%%word}`
>
> The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename
>   expansion. If the pattern matches a trailing portion of the expanded
>   value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the value of
>   parameter with the shortest matching pattern (the ‘%’ case) or the
>   longest matching pattern (the ‘%%’ case) deleted. If parameter is ‘@’
>   or ‘*’, the pattern removal operation is applied to each positional
>   parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list. If
>   parameter is an array variable subscripted with ‘@’ or ‘*’, the
>   pattern removal operation is applied to each member of the array in
>   turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.